# Unity player freezing due to script but without error

Tags: unity-game-engine

My unity player keeps on freezing after a while, I know what script is causing it (if it is indeed a script that is causing it). since there's only one script I've edited when it started freezing. But I can't figure out WHY it is freezing!
Here is the script that is causing it:

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {

//public GameObject allPlayersPrefab;
public GameObject allPlayers;
public Transform playerRed;
public Transform playerGreen;
//public Transform playerPurple;
//public Transform playerYellow;

//Tail redTail;
//Tail greenTail;
//Tail purpleTail;
//Tail yellowTail;

public float secondsBetweenGaps = 2f;
public float secondsToGap = .25f;

public float snakeSpeed = 3f;
public float turnSpeed = 200f;

public int biggerPickupDuration = 3;
public int smallerPickupDuration = 3;
public int speedPickupDuration = 2;
public int invinciblePickupDuration = 3;

public int maxPickups = 3;
public int spawnPickupThreshold = 5;
private GameObject[] currPickups;
public GameObject[] pickupTypes;
public Transform pickupsParent;

public int players = 2;

[HideInInspector]
public int alive;

public bool enableKeys = false;

public GameObject prefabTail;
public GameObject settingsMenu;
public GameObject startingPanel;

public Text scoreText;
public Text radiusText;
public Text speedText;

public Text winText;

private bool hasEnded = false;
[HideInInspector]
public bool playerWon = false;
public bool running;

public Snake[] snakes;

ButtonManager buttonManager;
Pickup[] pickups;

void Start() {
    //InstantiateNewPlayers();
    playerRed = allPlayers.transform.FindChild("Red");
    playerGreen = allPlayers.transform.FindChild("Green");
    snakes = allPlayers.GetComponentsInChildren<Snake>(true);
    alive = players;
    //redTail = playerRed.GetComponentInChildren<Tail>();
    //greenTail = playerGreen.GetComponentInChildren<Tail>();
    //purpleTail = playerPurple.GetComponentInChildren<Tail>();
    //yellowTail = playerYellow.GetComponentInChildren<Tail>();

    buttonManager = FindObjectOfType<ButtonManager>();

    pickups = FindObjectsOfType<Pickup>();

    playerRed.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    playerGreen.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    //playerPurple.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    //playerYellow.gameObject.SetActive(false);

    winText.enabled = false;

    foreach(Snake snake in snakes) {
        snake.scoreText.enabled = false;
    }
}

void Update() {
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Escape)) {
        foreach(Snake snake in snakes) {
            snake.score = 0;
            snake.scoreText.text = "0";
        }

        buttonManager.anima.Play("BackToSettings");
        playerWon = true;
        ResetGame();
        buttonManager.restartButt.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        buttonManager.StopAllCoroutines();
        buttonManager.countDownText.enabled = false;
        winText.enabled = false;

        foreach(Snake snake in snakes) {
            snake.scoreText.enabled = false;
        }
    }

    if(alive == 1 && !hasEnded) {
        Transform lastPlayer;
        foreach(Snake child in snakes) {
            if(!child.dead) {
                lastPlayer = child.transform.parent;
                if(child.score >= int.Parse(scoreText.text)) {
                    Win(lastPlayer.name);
                    AllPlayersDead();
                } else
                    AllPlayersDead();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if(alive == 0) {
        if(hasEnded)
            return;

        buttonManager.restartButt.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        hasEnded = true;
        running = false;
    }

    foreach(Snake child in snakes) {
        if(child.score >= int.Parse(scoreText.text)) {
            AllPlayersDead();
            Win(child.transform.parent.name);
        }
    }
}

public void AllPlayersDead() {
    if(hasEnded)
        return;

    buttonManager.restartButt.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    hasEnded = true;
    running = false;
}

void Win(string winningPlayer) {

    foreach(Snake snake in snakes) {
        snake.score = 0;
        snake.scoreText.text = "0";
    }
    Debug.Log("Win got called");
    winText.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    winText.enabled = true;
    winText.text = winningPlayer + " wins!";
    playerWon = true;
    running = false;
}

public void PlayerDied() {
    foreach(Snake child in snakes) {
        if(!child.dead) {
            child.score += 1;
        }
    }
}

public IEnumerator SpawnPickups() {
    while(enabled) {
        Debug.Log("SpawnPickups running...");
        if(running) {
            if(pickupsParent.childCount < maxPickups) {
                int type = Random.Range(0, pickupTypes.Length);
                float X = Random.Range(-7f, 7f);
                float Y = Random.Range(-3f, 3f);
                Vector3 spawnPos = new Vector3(X, Y, 0);
                /*GameObject newPickup = */Instantiate(pickupTypes[type], spawnPos, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0), pickupsParent);
                Debug.Log("SpawnPickups instantiated new pickup...");
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(spawnPickupThreshold);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void ResetGame() {
    Debug.Log("Resetting everything...");
    for(int i = 0; i < players; i++) {

        Transform currPlayer = allPlayers.transform.GetChild(i);
        currPlayer.GetComponentInChildren<Tail>().points.Clear();
        currPlayer.GetComponentInChildren<Snake>().dead = false;
        currPlayer.GetComponentInChildren<Snake>().invincible = false;
        currPlayer.GetComponentInChildren<Snake>().posInformer.position = new Vector3(-20, 0, 0);
        if(playerWon) {
            currPlayer.GetComponentInChildren<Snake>().score = 0;
            playerWon = false;
        }

        //currPlayer.GetComponentInChildren<LineRenderer>().positionCount = 0;
        currPlayer.GetComponentInChildren<LineRenderer>().numPositions = 0;

        List<Vector2> list = new List<Vector2>();
        list.Add(new Vector2(0, 5));
        list.Add(new Vector2(0, 6));

        StopAllCoroutines();

        for(int i2 = 0; i2 < pickups.Length; i2++) {
            pickups[i2].StopAllCoroutines();
        }

        foreach(Transform pickup in pickupsParent) {
            Destroy(pickup.gameObject);
        }

        currPlayer.GetComponentInChildren<EdgeCollider2D>().points = list.ToArray();

        foreach(Transform child in currPlayer) {
            if(child.CompareTag("PrefabTail")) {
                Destroy(child.gameObject);
            }
        }

        currPlayer.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        currPlayer.GetComponentInChildren<Tail>().enabled = true;
        Destroy(GameObject.FindWithTag("PrefabTail"));

        turnSpeed = int.Parse(radiusText.text) * 10;
        snakeSpeed = float.Parse(speedText.text);
        alive = players;
        hasEnded = false;
        running = false;
    }

    Debug.Log("Resetting done.");
}
}
```

I do have a small suspection that the freezing has something to do with the SpawnPickups method and/or the part where it destroys the pickups in the ResetGame method.

Thanks!

Comment: Hmm is is safe to delete children in a foreach loop?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: Um I'm quite sure it's not good, because foreach loop run by index and not an iterator. In other word it's just another `for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++)`, if you delete the n-th element during the loop then the (n+1)-th element will become n-th, and you will be skipping elements

Comment: So I should do something like this: var children = new List<GameObject>();
foreach (Transform child in transform) children.Add(child.gameObject);
children.ForEach(child => Destroy(child));

Comment: And do you think this is causing the freezing?

Comment: I don't think this should be a problem - all `Destroy()` will do from a code perspective is set the references to the object to null; it won't remove it from the collection immediately, so the iterator won't get messed up. (Haven't looked closely enough to see what might actually be the problem, though.)

Comment: for(int i=transform.childCount; i >=0; i--){ /* this loop is what I usually use */}, and yes, I think it should be the cause

Comment: How is `SpawnPickups` called? I'm seeing potential for an infinite loop with that `while (enabled)`, especially if it's ever called and `running` is false.

Comment: It looks like you get an infinite loop in SpawnPickups when running is set to false in ResetGame and while enabled is still true causing an infinite loop, is my best guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method SpawnPickups is doing this.
When you call this coroutine, and enable is true and running is false, you never reach a "yield" instruction, so your while(enabled) is indeed a while(true)

Coroutines are not threads, they run on the main thread and if you block a coroutine like this one, you are blocking the game.

```
public IEnumerator SpawnPickups() {
    while(enabled) {
        Debug.Log("SpawnPickups running...");
        if(running) {
            if(pickupsParent.childCount < maxPickups) {
                int type = Random.Range(0, pickupTypes.Length);
                float X = Random.Range(-7f, 7f);
                float Y = Random.Range(-3f, 3f);
                Vector3 spawnPos = new Vector3(X, Y, 0);
                /*GameObject newPickup = */Instantiate(pickupTypes[type], spawnPos, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0), pickupsParent);
                Debug.Log("SpawnPickups instantiated new pickup...");
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(spawnPickupThreshold);
            }
            //Here you need some yield in case running is true but you reached maxPickups (this one is not necessary if you put the next one)
        }
        //Here you need some yield in case running is false
        //yield return null; //this should be enough to prevent your game from freezing
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it's not freezing anymore! But isn't it weird it didn't give me any errors? Oh and what do you think about destroying objects in a foreach loop (What AVAVT was talking about)?

Comment: It's perfectly normal that it doesn't give you any error, because it's not "failing", it's just stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: Destroying objects in a foreach loop can indeed give you some errors, but it won't freeze your app, it will just show those errors in the console and probably some weird behaviour, and maybe crashing. 
But won't freeze your unity app.

Comment: Actually, Destroying objects using "Destroy()" shouldn't be a problem at all in foreach loops, the real trouble comes when you add or remove items from the collection you are going through with the foreach loop, and "Destroy()" doesn't take place immediately, it just mark objects to be destroyed and they are destroyed all together between the current frame and the next one.